# Area of a surface

Tags: calculus, area, surface-integrals

The question is;

If the equation of a surface $S$ is $z = f(x, y)$, where $x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2$, and you know that $|f_x| \leq 1$ and $|f_y| \leq 1$, what can you say about $Area(S)$?

Options are:

1) $Area(S) = π^2R$

2) $πR^2 ≤ Area(S) ≤ \sqrt3πR^2$

3) $Area(S) > 3πR^2$

4) $πR ≤ Area(S) ≤ πR^2$

5) $πR ≤ Area(S) ≤ 3πR$

My workings so far:

$Area(S)= \iint_D \sqrt{(\frac{df}{du})^2 + (\frac{df}{dv})^2 +1} dA$

Since $|f_x| \leq 1$ and $|f_y| \leq 1$,

$Area(S)= \iint_D \sqrt{(\frac{df}{du})^2 + (\frac{df}{dv})^2 +1}dA \leq \iint_D \sqrt3 dA$

where the domain is $ D = ${$(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq R^2$}.

And now I'm stuck, where do I go from here?

If I had to guess, I would choose (option 2) $πR^2 ≤ Area(S) ≤ \sqrt3πR^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your work you obtain

$$\iint_D \sqrt3 dA=\sqrt 3\pi R^2$$

Comment: should it be $\leq$? and I don't understand how you got $\iint 1 dA = \pi R^2$

Comment: @LB2015 Note that the domain D is a circle of radius R.

Comment: @LB2015, for the lower bound, use $|f_x|,|f_y|\geq 0$ to get $\operatorname{Area}(S)\geq\iint\limits_D\mathrm dA=\pi R^2$, so we have, $$\pi R^2\leq\operatorname{Area}(S)\leq\sqrt 3\pi R^2$$

Comment: got it!!! integrating over a constant function - and lower bound is 0 for the partial derivatives. Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: @LB2015, the lower bound isn't $0$ for the partial derivatives, but for their absolute values (we use the trivial inequality for the lower bound).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas - now i'm confused again. so the absolute values for the partial derivatives are $\geq 0$, why then can we just substitute 0 straight into the equation? or are we not doing that - I guess I don't really understand why the upper bound absolute value is just subbing in 1 either

Comment: @LB2015 Note that $$\iint_D dA=\pi R^2\le Area(S)= \iint_D \sqrt{(\frac{df}{du})^2 + (\frac{df}{dv})^2 +1} \,dA \le \iint_D \sqrt3 dA=\sqrt 3\pi R^2$$

Comment: @LB2015, We can do it because the formula involves the squares of the partial derivatives and for any $x\in\Bbb R$, we have $x^2\geq 0$ (this is called the trivial inequality).

Comment: I see - Thanks @PrasunBiswas

Answer (score 1):

You have it right here $$Area(S)= \iint_D \sqrt{(\frac{df}{du})^2 + (\frac{df}{dv})^2 +1}dA \leq \iint_D \sqrt3 dA=    \sqrt 3\pi R^2     $$